# Принудительный парсинг строки

Tags: php

Все знают о замечательной возможности PHP парсить строки в двойных кавычках на наличие переменных

```
$who = 'World';
$greeting = "Hello {$who}"; // Hello World
```

Но, возможно ли нативным образом отложить парсинг до поры до времени? Предположим задав строку вида `Hello {$who}` как некий шаблон, не производя немедленного парсинга, а сделав его потом, когда `$who` будет определена? К примеру:

```
$who = NULL;
$greetingPattern = 'Hello {$who}'; // String has not parsed yet
$who = 'World'; // Set value to who
$greeting = SomeParseFunction($greetingPattern); // Hello World
```

Comment: как вариант сперва записать в переменную какой-то мусор, а потом переопределить ее в момент //Set value to who

Comment: Хотелось бы программировать без мусора.

Answer (score 2):

На скорую руку:

```
$greetingPattern = 'Hello {$foo} + {$bar}';
$foo = 'foo';
$bar = 'bar';

$greeting = SomeParseFunction($greetingPattern, get_defined_vars());

function SomeParseFunction($greetingPattern, $definedVars)
{
    preg_match_all('/\$[a-z]+/', $greetingPattern, $matches);
    foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
        $name = str_replace('$', '', $match);
        if (isset($definedVars[$name])) {
            $greetingPattern = str_replace('{$' . $name . '}', $definedVars[$name], $greetingPattern);
        }
    }

    return $greetingPattern;
}

echo $greeting; // => Hello foo + bar
```

Несколько коряво, но идея прослеживается. Возможно, кто-нибудь сделает этот код лучше...

Comment: Вы видимо не обратили внимание на то, что я указал на нативность решения. Писать парсеры - эта самая крайняя мера. Впрочем я уже нашел решение.

Comment: @VladimirMorulus, не через **eval** нашли решение?

Comment: Именно через него

Comment: @VladimirMorulus забудьте про `eval`, лучше как в ответе выше

Comment: @VladimirMorulus У всех, конечно, разные представления о крайних мерах, но я начитался и для себя принял eval настолько крайней мерой, что никогда его не использовал. А парсеры писал :)

Comment: @korytoff поясните, почему я должен забыть про eval?

Comment: @VladimirMorulus потому что это потенциальная дыра в безопасности – http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Возможно sprintf это то, что вам надо:

```
$pattern = 'Hello %s';
$who = 'World';
$greeting = sprintf($pattern, $who);
echo $greeting;
```

И, пожалуйста, в следующий раз когда захотите использовать `eval` подумайте дважды.

Comment: Ваше пример не решает задачу. Мне не нужна строка вида 'Hello %s', а нужна конкретно 'Hello {$who}' и нативный парсинг.

Comment: Я не знаю, по какой причине вы так впряглись в «нативный парсинг», но мое решение в 10 раз быстрее вашего, если что.

Answer (score -1):

Нашел решение.

```
$test = 'Hello {$who}';
$who = 'World';
eval("\$greeting = \"$test\";");
echo $greeting;
```

Comment: надеюсь в переменной `$who` данные из гет запроса? ))

Comment: @korytoff неть не изь геть запрося))) тема моего вопроса была не о безопасности php.